# unable to find why and how the output is 128

Tags: java

I have some confusion regarding below program. here I got output as 128.

```
    int i=0;
        while(Integer.valueOf(i)==Integer.valueOf(i))
            i++;
        System.out.println(i);

output: 128
```

Comment: Exactly. To figure it our yourself, change `valueOf` to `parseInt` and see what happens.

Comment: @ user3469481 here parseInt won't work. as i is int.

Answer (score 4):

The JVM caches `int` values between -128 and 127 for the `Integer` class. Therefore, the following statement will return true upto 127 :

```
Integer.valueOf(i)==Integer.valueOf(i)
```

Beyond 127, `valueOf` returns a new `Integer` object by default.

On the last iteration of your `while` loop, `i` will be 127 and `i++` will change it to 128. That's why the output is 128 and not 127.